# Как получить определенный объект из массива в fetch запросе?

Tags: javascript, api, promise, fetch

Я не смог найти ответ на свой вопрос в интернете, и я думаю, что это будет полезно для других, если кто-то знающий сможет ответить на него.
Я хочу использовать утилиту - *World Time API*, но столкнулся с проблемой, я отправляю запрос fetch, получаю результат в виде JSON строки. Но это объект, а мне нужна конкретный ключ, как я могу это сделать?
Например, как получить ключ timezone, чтобы потом использовать значение?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
fetch('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
        console.log(json)
    })
```

Comment: И заголовок переведи

Comment: Добавь пример, какой конкретно запрос ты делаешь, и пример ответа, который получаешь

Comment: Например, запрос на `http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Moscow` возвращает не массив, а отдельный объект, поэтому не понятно в чем именно проблема у тебя?

Comment: Код, нужно добавить текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: мне нужно из объекта забрать определенный ключ, чтобы потом взять оттуда значение

Comment: `json.timezone` - странно почему для `response` ты догадался как обратиться к полю, а для json - нет

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне сделать из этого новую данную, чтобы в будущем я смог к ней обращаться в коде?

Comment: Что ты имеешь ввиду?

Comment: Ну вот смотри, исходя из json.timezone, я получил таймзону - London. Я хочу использовать эту таймзону дальше в коде, например, для часов (условно). Как мне это сделать? Как мне сделать так, чтобы дальше, по ходу кода, я мог спокойно обращаться к этой переменной и она мне показывала таймзону, исходя из моего fetch запроса.

Comment: Мне нужно создать как-то переменную и туда поместить результат моего fetch запроса? Типо const fetch = "url"?

Comment: Смотри в дубликате пример

Comment: @Grundy а как я могу обратиться к определенному значению тут?
(await data.json());
если пишу (await data.json.timezone) - определяет как undefined

Comment: как и в любом другом объекте, ставишь точку и указываешь имя свойства.

Comment: _если пишу (await data.json.timezone)_ - что такое `data`? что такое `json`? и почему ты перед этим ставишь `await`?

Comment: Всю необходимую информацию добавляй непосредственно в вопрос, иначе не видно что откуда у тебя берется.

Comment: За основу я взял твой пример из дубликата, 

`(async function() {
  var data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  console.log(await data.json());
})();`

Я правильно же понимаю, что дата, в твоем случае, - это переменная, которую потом мы определяем? Если не тот пример смотрю, исправь, пожалуйста.

Мне нужно получить из _fetch_ запроса переменную, чтобы потом вставить ее _HTML div_ для работы со временем.

Comment: Тот пример. `await data.json()` и возвращает объект, который ты можешь присвоить переменной и у которого взять нужное свойство.